# Embedded/iframe-ed Leaflet map not displaying properly in Squarespace

Tags: javascript, iframe, leaflet, squarespace

I built a custom map with Leaflet that works on my personal website subdirectory when I go directly to it in a browser.

I inserted a code block in my Squarespace site like this:

```
<iframe src="http://www.website.com/test/leaflet/" width="100%" height="540"></iframe>
```

When I view this, an empty white square appears on my Squarespace page.  It is the dimensions I set with the width and height parameters.  And no error message is thrown.  But the map itself is not rendering.

Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Answer (score 1):

You are likely running into an issue related to the protocol you are using to load the iframe. Remove `https:` from the start of the `src` attribute. If that works, that confirms the issue.

If your [Squarespace website will be using SSL](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/205815898-Squarespace-and-SSL) with your custom domain (`https`), then you'll want to replace `http:` with `https:` instead of removing it altogether. If your Squarespace website will be using `http` then you'll want to either use the protocol relative version (mentioned in the first paragraph above) or stick with `http:` and accept that you will be unable to view the iframe when logged in and editing your website via the admin/config interface.

Comment: I removed the `http:` from the start of the `src` attribute and it was definitely a step in the right direction: an html header I have in the source map (the index.html) appeared inside the iframe in Squarespace.  However the map itself does not render.  Why would it have trouble with the map itself and not the html/css?

Comment: I also tried another modification changing it to `https:` and that also had the same effect as my comment directly above.